# What does the Cpy%Sync column of lvs output mean for a cache LV?

Tags: lvm, dm-cache

I have a host with a single cache LV (~800GB SSD in front of a multi-TB RAID array; write-through mode). I ran a routine scrub on the RAID last night (`lvchange --syncaction check`). Ever since that completed, the system has been running at 100% I/O capacity; `iostat` tells me it's reading data from the SSD and writing to the RAID.

The `Cpy%Sync` column of `lvs` output for the cache LV (*not* the RAID) started out at 98% or so before the scrub, which was worrisome in itself, but now it is steadily going *down*, having currently reached about 70%.

I thought `Cpy%Sync` for a cache LV indicated the amount of data on the cache that also existed on the backing store, so in write-through mode it should always be 100%. What does it actually mean and what is the system doing that's making it go down steadily?

There is nothing helpful in dmesg.

Answer (score 0):

According to the lvmraid man pages [1]:

> Automatic synchronization happens when a RAID LV is activated,
> but it is usually partial because the bitmaps reduce the areas
> that are checked.  A full sync becomes necessary when devices in
> the RAID LV are replaced.
>
> The synchronization status of a RAID LV is reported by the
> following command, where "Cpy%Sync" = "100%" means sync is
> complete:
>
> `lvs -a -o name,sync_percent`

Another excerpt:

> When integrity is added to an LV, the kernel
> needs to initialize the integrity metadata (checksums) for all blocks
> in the LV.  The data corruption checking performed by dm-integrity
> will only operate on areas of the LV that are already initialized.
> The progress of integrity initialization is reported by the
> "syncpercent" LV reporting field (and under the Cpy%Sync lvs column.)

However, another source claiming a similar problem [2] mentions the following in regards to the disk activity:

> Cache is always flushing it's content to disk - so if you have the
> 'writeback' variant and there were some unwritten data which sits only
> in cache, they are automatically pushed to origin (cached) device -
> which is likely your disk activity.

1. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmraid.7.html
2. https://listman.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2015-June/msg00001.html